# Error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token - Functions

Tags: c++

As the title says. 
I have no idea how to fix this error, 
**I am aware that much of my code is wrong. However I am specifically talking about line 9**

This line below is where I have the error. I have excluded all other parts where I have declared the variable.

```
    bool primeChecker(checked)
    {
    int checker = 2;
    while(checker <= checked)
        {
        if(checked % checker == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        checker++;
        }
    return true;
    }

//Here it does the counting n' stuff,
int main()
{
    cout << "How many primes will you be checking? \n";
    cin >> nTCheck;
    while(nChecked <= nTCheck)
    {
       if (checked == primeChecker(checked))
       {
           cout << "Prime number " << nChecked << " is: " << checked << " \n";
           nChecked++;
           checked++;
       }
       checked++;

    }
cout << "That is all, folks!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please specify what line 9 refers to in your code

Comment: You can name your variables anything you want.  Using a naming scheme that involves variable/function names like this is confusing.  Particularly `checker` versus `checked` within the `primeChecker()` function...

Comment: It seems that people had trouble figuring out where line 9 was. I had the first line here, (in the code above) be line 9. That's where the error was. Also, I did not include the part where I had declared the variable.             It seems that adding "int" in front of 'checked' solved the problem. Although now I get another error :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is on your first line of the code you posted:

```
bool primeChecker(checked) { }
//checked is undeclared, Change it to int checked
bool primeChecker(int checked){ }
                 ^^^^^
```

Comment: For clarity (I know you've stated it's on the first line), the header is wrong in the function definition.  There's nothing wrong with line 9 where the function is being called.